# Html table with vertical <tr> and PHP arrays

Tags: php, css, html-table

I have a PHP array that I want to increment through and output the information in a table. The only problem is the way HTML tables are organized. I want to output the data vertically.

For example - the first row shows every day of the week, then below each day it would show vertically what food some restaurant is serving. It would show 5 dishes straight down from each day of the week.

Since tables are separated into `<tr>` (horizontal) and then `<td>` that only gives you horizontal output. So the only way I can think of an answer is either a PHP answer or a CSS/html answer.

```
Example:
TR - TD - TD - TD 
TR - TD - TD - TD 
TR - TD - TD - TD
```

Is there a way to have `<tr>` display vertically and then be seperated by `<td>` horizontally?

```
Example like this:
TR TR TR
|   |  |
TD TD  TD
|   |  |
TD TD  TD
```

Comment: It is a 2-d array: Days then Items for the day and it is made dynamically.

Comment: if there is no way to change the direction of TRs then I have to figure out a php answer which probably involves a few for-loops

Comment: or I could ignore tables all together and use divs because those break down vertically by default

Comment: nevermind... answered my own question there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. If you add `display: block` to the `<td>` elements then they start stacking on top of each other. Maybe im just burnt out and over thought the answer... Thanks anways

Comment: This method is actually better because the content in the source is output in order, so it would be read by a screen reader in a logical order. However, you're probably going to need to float the `TR` elements left.

Comment: I didnt even think of screen readers, but that is good to hear. Ya i had to float the TR elements.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work. I guessed on the kind of data you have, but basically you just find the day with the most items, create a `th` for each day, create a `tr` for as many items that are in the biggest day, and finally create a `td` for each day that prints the item corresponding to the for loop counter.

```php
<?php

$mon_arr = array("mon 1", "mon 2", "mon 3");
$tue_arr = array("tue 1", "tue 2", "tue 3", "tue 4");
$wed_arr = array("wed 1", "wed 2", "wed 3", "wed 4");
$thu_arr = array("thu 1", "thu 2");
$fri_arr = array("fri 1", "fri 2", "fri 3", "fri 4", "fri 5");
$sat_arr = array("sat 1");
$sun_arr = array("sun 1");

$week = array(
    "Monday"    => $mon_arr,
    "Tuesday"   => $tue_arr,
    "Wednesday" => $wed_arr,
    "Thursday"  => $thu_arr,
    "Friday"    => $fri_arr,
    "Saturday"  => $sat_arr,
    "Sunday"    => $sun_arr
);


$max_day = 0;

foreach($week as $day => $data){

    $current = count($data);

    if($current > $max_day){
        $max_day = $current;
    }
}

?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach( $week as $day => $data ){
                    echo "<th>$day</th>";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php for( $i = 0; $i < $max_day; $i++ ){ ?>
        <tr>

            <?php
                foreach( $week as $day => $data ){

                    if( $data[$i] ){
                        echo "<td>$data[$i]</td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                    }

                }
            ?>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```