# How to show table in columns from to to bottom?

Tags: php

I have array:

```
$array = [
    'category1' => [
        'product33',
        'product41'
    ], 
    'category2' => [
        'product1',
        'product45'
    ], 
    'category3' => [
        'product65',
        'product23',
        'product423'
    ], 
];
```

How can I show this data from array in table from top to bottom?

This should looks this:

```
category1  | category 2 | category3
product33  | product1   | product65
product41  | product45  | product23
           |            | product423
```

I tried:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <?php foreach ($array as $category): ?>
         <td><?php echo $category ?></td>
     <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
//????
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean top to bottom? do you want to show in data in multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610477/html-table-with-vertical-tr-and-php-arrays)

First calculate the `$max_products`. Then print header (category1, category2, etc). Then in nested loop print elements in rows to `$max_products` (you need to check if that category has element with index `$i` ofc).

```
$max_products = 0;

foreach($array as $category => $products){

    $current = count($products);

    if($current > $max_products){
        $max_products = $current;
    }
}?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach( $array as $category => $products ){
                    echo "<th>$category</th>";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php for( $i = 0; $i < $max_products; $i++ ){ ?>
        <tr>

            <?php
                foreach( $array as $category => $products ){

                    if( $products[$i] ){
                        echo "<td>$products[$i]</td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                    }

                }
            ?>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'category1' => [
        'product33',
        'product41'
    ],
    'category2' => [
        'product1',
        'product45'
    ],
    'category3' => [
        'product65',
        'product23',
        'product423'
    ],
];

$maxSize = 0;
foreach ($data as $category) {
    $maxSize = max($maxSize, count($category));
}

for ($i=-1; $i<$maxSize; $i++) {
    foreach ($data as $key=>$category) {
        if (-1 === $i) {
            echo $key . "\t";
        } else {
            echo isset($category[$i]) ? $category[$i] . "\t" : "\t\t";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
category1       category2       category3
product33       product1        product65
product41       product45       product23
                                product423
```

Note: this is meant to be used on CLI for demonstration purpose. The additional html markup would only bloat the code demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
 foreach ($array as $category)
 {
   echo "<td>" . key($array) . "</td>";

   foreach ($category as $item)
   {
     echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";
   }
   next($array);
 }
?>
```